# Linux Filesystem: Automatic/Continuous disk usage accounting

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage

I am interested in having a Linux filesystem which does automatic/continuous accounting of disk usage (e.g. tracks the size of all files and directories so that tools like `du` return quickly).

The Linux filesystem quota system does something similar: it performs continual accounting to show the usage per-user or per-group when running the `repquota` command ... but this does not allow us to "instant `du`" on our directories (to find the top consumers).

I believe Ceph has a mechanism for this. However, I won't be using Ceph for my project.

**What are some more general approaches to this?** (e.g. names of filesystem-agnostic tools, general use POSIX filesystems that have this as a feature, etc)

Perhaps a more general question is about having metadata operations return quickly in general (not just accounting for sizes like `du`, but quickly finding/counting things with `ls` / `find` and so on). If there are answers that overlap with that area, feel free to let me know also!